# C-Style data fiddling in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

Is there any Python module that allows one to freely reinterpret raw bytes as different data types and perform various arithmetic operations on them? For example, take a look at this C snippet:

```
char test[9] = "test_data";
int32_t *x = test;
(*x)++;
printf("%d %.9s\n", x, test);

//outputs 1245780400 uest_data on LE system.
```

Here, both `test` and `x` point to the same chunk of memory. I can use `x` to perform airthmetics and `test`for string-based operations and individual byte access.

I would like to do the same in Python - I know that I can use `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` whenerver I feel the need to convert between list of bytes and an integer, but maybe there's a module that makes such fiddling much easier.

I'd like to have a datatype that would support arithmetics and at the same time, would allow me to mess with the individual bytes. This doesn't sound like a use-case that Python was designed for, but nevertheless, it's a quite common problem.

I took a look into `pycrypto` codebase, since cryptography is one of the most common use cases for such functionality, but `pycrypto` implements most of its algorithms in plain C and the much smaller Python part uses two handcrafted methods (`long_to_bytes` and `bytes_to_long`) for conversion between the types.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `ctypes.Union`, which is analogous to Unions in C.

I don't have much experience in C, but as I understand Unions allow you to write to a memory location as one type and read it as another type, and vice versa, which seems to fit your use case.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions

Otherwise, if your needs are simpler, you could just convert `bytes` / `bytearray` objects from / to integers using the built-in `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes` methods.

Comment: While unions do not directly solve my problem, they would definitely help. Thanks!